# Gaussian Curve Fitting with Offset

Tags: java, apache-commons, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have to fit a Gaussian curve to data points where 1 peak is expected. The data points can have an arbitrary offset in the y-direction.

I am using the `org.apache.commons.math3` package. However, when creating a `GaussianCurveFitter` instance, it is only possible to pass the following initial guess values:

- Normalization
- Mean
- Sigma

Right now I have come this far:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.GaussianCurveFitter;
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.WeightedObservedPoints;

public void fitGaussian(double[] data) {
WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();
//add data points
for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    obs.add(j, data[j]);
}

//fit gaussian curve
double[] parameters = GaussianCurveFitter.create().fit(obs.toList());
}
```

Here the `parameters` contain above mentioned values (Normalization, Mean, Sigma).

Does anybody have an idea how I can also include the offset in y-direction as a free optimization parameter? Or maybe how to transform the original data points to suit the optimizer?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello, have you now solved this problem?